# Android app doesn't work in others devices

Tags: java, android

When I run my app with Android Studio in my physical device (Device 1), it's work fine, later when I share my app with other device(Device 2), doesn't work (App has stopped responding).

Too, when I run my app in Device 2 works fine and when share the app with Device 1 doesn't work.

I've seen that when I run the app directly with Android Studio, this create a app package in my device in : data/app. And when I install manually the app in the other device, the package is not created.

This problem didn't happen when I had `Android Studio 2.2`, but now I have the version 2.3 and have this problem.

Comment: What are your android devices versions?

Comment: 4.4 in all devices

Answer (score 0):

the android 6 need real time permission .

when you run the app in your device it doesn't ask you the real time permissions, but when you share your app it need to ask permission from the user. i think you didn't handle the permission issues.

Comment: when you run the app in your device, it is supposed to ask runtime permission that time too, if running on 6.0+.

Comment: @Sanjeet but iam working in an app on 6.0.1 and i it works fine without getting permessions.

Comment: unless you have set the targetSDK below 23 or already granted the permission, you need to ask for runtime permission if you want to use anything from "dangerous permissions group".  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: yes the target SDK is below 23 but i delete that much time and use the location of the device without giving any real time permission .

Comment: @e-hadid  if the targetSDK is below 23 then all the permissions that are listed in AndroidManifest.xml are granted by default. If you want to check then try setting the targetSDK to 23 or above, or go to app setting and revoke the permission and check

Comment: sorry i think you say min SDK
my target SDK is 23 and working without real time permission

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141816/discussion-between-e-hadid-and-sanjeet).

Comment: So, what permission should I add?

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere on your device previous app was still installed even though sometimes it doesnot show up in the app drawer try removing it from `settings>Apps`, and see if it works .